# How to check if someone mentioned me in a telegram group using telethon events?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

I'm trying to make a filters like in **Pyrogram** that checking if someone mentioned me in a group, this is how I did it with pyrogram:

```
@bot.on_message(filters.mentioned & filters.group)
def mentioned(bot, message):
    do_response(message)
```

I need the same way in **Telethon**. But I can't find the right documentation or tutorials for that!

Answer (score 2):

BTW. I've done it this way:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True)
async def incoming(event):
    if event.is_group and event.mentioned:
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer, or an update to your question? In the former case, please read [answer], then [edit] this accordingly. In the latter case, please delete this and edit your question instead.